# How to select from the list only some properties depending from list of property names?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, system.reflection

I am looking for selection where the result is anonymous but the properties are given from list of string

Example

```
public class A{
     public string PropertyA {get; set;}
     public double PropertyB {get; set;}
     public double PropertyC {get; set;}
     public double PropertyD {get; set;}
}

var list = new List<A>{ ... };

var propertyNames = new List<string>{"PropertyA", "PropertyD"}
```

I would like create a **selector**  which creates an anonymous with PropertyA and PropertyD, so I can get something like

```
var result = list.Select( selector(propertynames) ).ToList();
```

where again result[0] is anonymous with properties like  result[0].PropertyA and result[0].PropertyD

Comment: @TheGeneral what actually I need is to serialize the final list and pass as result of query. Imagine it as result from an sql select in DB...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really, *really* suggest going differently about this.
However, here is one way to approach this problem - use `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject`:

```
var result = list
    .Select(i =>
    {
        var expando = new ExpandoObject();
        var expandoAsDict = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;
        var targetProperties = i
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => propertyNames.Contains(p.Name))
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(i));
        foreach (var property in targetProperties)
        {
            expandoAsDict.Add(property);
        }
        return (dynamic)expando;
    })
    .ToList();
```

You can then proceed as you describe, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(result[0].PropertyA);
```

writes out the expected value.

Of course you can forget about Intellisense support for your dynamic type (if that wasn't obvious to begin with).
Note: another approach would be to construct your type at runtime by using `System.Reflection.Emit`, but that would be even more awkward.

Good luck!